# bad operand types for binary operator '<='

Tags: java, mergesort

I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this error. I've tried putting everything in parenthesis and that helped the problem a little bit. It would be great if I could get some help.

**Code :**

```
public void merge(String[] result, String[] nameA, String[] nameB)
{
    int i1 = 0;   // index into nameA array
    int i2 = 0;   // index into nameB array

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) 
    {
        if (i2 >= nameB.length || (i1 < nameA.length && nameA[i1] <= nameB[i2])) 
        {
            result[i] = nameA[i1];    // take from nameA
            i1++;
        } 
        else 
        {
            result[i] = nameB[i2];   // take from nameB
            i2++;
        }
    }
}
```

> error: bad operand types for binary operator '<='

Comment: What is the full text of the error? What are the operand types? Can you use those types with `<=`?

Comment: Why are you trying to do a `less than or equal to` operation on `String`s?

Comment: The fundamental problem is that in Java, unlike some other languages, you can't use `<=` (or `<`, `>`, and similar) to compare strings lexigraphically (or indeed, at all). So the error is created by the `nameA[i1] <= nameB[i2]` part. The solution is found in Ivaylo's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the answers of Luiggi Mendoza and Ivaylo Strandjev I like to point out that if you only want to make sure the strings differ, you can use equals like this:

```
if (i2 >= nameB.length || (i1 < nameA.length && !nameA[i1].equals(nameB[i2])))
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to compare `String`s in Java you need to call the method `compareTo`. Have a look at the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface that `String` implements.

Answer (score 5):

`<=` and `>=` operators are for numeric primitive types like `int` or `double`. To compare `String`s, use `compareTo` method.

```
nameA[i1].compareTo(nameB[i2]) < 0
```

If you want to compare `String`s by length, then use `<=` operator on [`String#length`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) instead:

```
nameA[i1].length() <= nameB[i2].length()
```